# Applying ellipsis to one child element but not the other

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I have the following layout:

```
<div>
  <div1>
    <span1></span>
    <span2></span>
  </div>
  <div2>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Div1 has the property `flex-grow: 1` so that it can take up all the available space it needs.

When div1 takes up all the space it needs and when the browser window is made smaller, span1 should get ellipsis while span2 should not.

How can I do this? I have tried various uses of flex, adding more divs, and changing width with no success.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was turning both span1 and span2 into divs. Setting a hardcoded width on span2(div2) then setting the width on span1(div1) to

```
max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 110px);
max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 110px);
max-width: -o-calc(100% - 110px);
max-width: calc(100% - 110px);
```

where 110px is the width on span2(div2)

Comment: Thanks! Also to anyone who uses this the multiple max-widths are for browser support. I ended up only using calc.

Comment: it's hard to understand the question can you post a working demo of above solution? You might be able to do it with nested flexbox.